# How to call solr analysis api in java?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

Is there a way to call solrs analysis api in java using solr-core and get the analyzed tokens.

Analysis api takes `fieldName` or `fieldType` and values and give the analyzed tokens.

Is there a way to get those tokens from java?

I found the following link: [FieldAnalysisRequestHandler](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/handler/FieldAnalysisRequestHandler.html), But I could not get any examples to use it.

Comment: So what have you tried mister 'give me teh codez' ?

Comment: if  this problem has been resolved , please tell me ， if not，i have a analysis example ， it maybe useful for you！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Admin UI (for which the `FieldAnalysisRequestHandler` is meant) you can call it by selecting a core and then go to the "Analysis" entry.
See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/UYDxAQ or https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/FoDxAQ for that.

From a client (which I guess you mean, as you tagged this question with `solrj`) you need to call the correct URL.
Typically the `FieldAnalysisRequestHandler` is bound to `/analysis/field`, see your `solrconfig.xml`.

From Solrj it should work like this:

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
solrQuery.setRequestHandler("/analysis/field");
solrQuery.set("analysis.fieldtype", "mytype");
solrQuery.set("analysis.fieldvalue", "myval");
QueryResponse solrResponse = solrServer.query(solrQuery);
```

But it doesn't seem like there's a great support for this in Solrj, probably because it's meant to be called from the Solr Admin UI as mentioned.